# Use adjusted local fallback font with Bootstrap 5 for different font weights

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am currently trying to reduce cumulative layout shift by using an adjusted local font as fallback. For the regular font this works quite well. But, in the above-the-fold content of the website, we also have a couple of bold formatted sentences.

Is there any clean way to also give the other font weights a fallback in Bootstrap 5?

Of course, outside of Bootstrap I could just name the bold font "Mulish Bold" and add a fallback for it. But in Bootstrap, I would have to add ugly overwrites of a couple of elements like `.fw-bold`, `b`, `strong`, etc. what seems to be quite ugly.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Mulish Regular Fallback';
  src: local(Tahoma);
  size-adjust: 103%;
  ascent-override: 100%;
  descent-override: 23%;
  line-gap-override: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Mulish';
  font-display: swap;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/Mulish-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Mulish';
  font-display: swap;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts/Mulish-Bold.ttf');
}

// In Bootstrap Variables:
$font-family-sans-serif: 'Mulish', 'Mulish Regular Fallback', sans-serif;
```